# Can pine-script filter the multiple stocks based on conditions and pop up alert for all

Tags: pine-script

I am looking for a small help like can we filter the list of stocks based on some conditions and pop up the alert.

If suppose I want to pop up alert whenever any stocks's close price is crossing previous 6 candle high

Answer (score 0):

You can use the security function to pull data from other assets, and use it up to 40 times in a script.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_security

So pull the data you need, make a function that tests the data, then run it on all of the security function data and use it to generate your alert.

A simple way to do this is to create an string array, then have a function add a string to it whenever the result is true. Then if the array size is greater than 0, trigger an alert with an `array.join(alertsArray, ', ')` as the text.